# How to Display message once we got response from Browser

Tags: php

we select checbox & onclick button "**Show Status**" , I am calling external webservice api url & updating the "**status**" column [4th in below image] values in Database.....

[image]

**Requirement** :

I want to show the message "**completed**" once if we got response from browser :

[image]

**status page**

```
<button type= "button" id="show_status" >Show Status</button>
```

**script**

```
$('#show_status').click(function(){ 
var selected = []; 
$('.assigneeid-order:checked').each(function() { 
selected.push($(this).val()); 
$('.assigneeid-order').prop('checked', false);
}); 

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(selected); 

$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: "api.php", 
data: {data : jsonString}, 
success: function(response){ 

response = $.parseJSON(response);

$.each(response, function(index, val) { 

$("#"+index+"").html(val);
$("#"+index+"").html(val.status); 

}); 
} 
}); 

});
```

**api.php**

```
 <?php

$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data'])); 
$response = array(); 

foreach($data as $id){ 

$post_data['username']='a';
$url = 'https://plapi.ecomexpress.in/track_me/api/mawbd/'; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_close($ch); 

$orderResults=$xml=simplexml_load_string($output);
//print_r($orderResults); die;
    foreach($orderResults->object as $child)
    {
      $status=(string)$child->field[10];         
      break;
     }

$statusfinal = str_replace('<field type="CharField" name="status">','',$status); 

if($statusfinal!='') 
{ 
$sqlecom = "UPDATE do_order set in_transit='".$status."' where tracking_id=".$orderid;
//echo $sqlecom;

$db_handleecom = new DBController(); 
$resultecom = $db_handleecom->executeUpdate($sqlecom); 
} 
$response[$orderid] = [ 'status' => $status ];
}
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: in your ajax call, `success: function(response){  }` this is where you can add your message, you have the response of the server.

Comment: By the way, an indented code is more pleasant to read.

Comment: @Cid Thanks a lot, please post your comment as answer.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an ajax call, the member `success` is being used when the request succedeeds. You can use this method to inform the user the server gave a success response.

```
success: function(response){ 

    //Your code here to inform the user

    response = $.parseJSON(response);

    $.each(response, function(index, val) { 

        $("#"+index+"").html(val);
        $("#"+index+"").html(val.status); 

    }); 
}
```

You can use the member `error` the same way to tell the user that the server indicated that the request failed.

```
error: function(response)
{
    //not good, tell it to the user
}
```

Comment: thanks, if we select hundreds of rows, than it will take more time, so how to show progress..... example : `1 %, 2 % like that....`

Comment: hi, can you please help me for this ?

Comment: This is another question, but the percent can be calculated using `(numberOfFinishedRequests / numberOfRequest) * 100;`

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

You can add a div in display none in your HTML and put it in display block when you have an answer from the broswer.

In your success function in your ajax code, you put the code to do it.

Example:
   

    $('#completed-message').text('Completed');

```
$('#completed-message').css('display', 'block');
```

Comment: @vickeycolors alert is not user friendly. I hate when being bothered by such popup

Comment: @Cid Thanks for answer, please give me some time, i will chek with my boss , how he want the message to display......

Comment: sorry, our boss is fine with alert box, but `if we select hundreds of rows, than it will take more time, so how to show progress.....`

Comment: if you receive answers one after the others, you can check you receive a message yet thanks to a boolean. You set the boolean to false then when you receive a message, you set the boolean to false.

Comment: @eclairia sorry , i didt understood, are you telling about displaying `progress message` ?